# Powershell : Extract Second line from String

Tags: powershell, substring

I wish to select the thirdline of text from a sting in powershell.

The string I have is coming from the body of an email:

```
  $olFolderInbox = 6
  $outlook = new-object -com outlook.application;
  $ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
  $inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)

   foreach ($email in $inbox.items){

         if($email.Subject -eq "PASSED") {

         $Body = $email.Body 

         write-host  $emailSentOn
         write-host  $email.Body 

        } 
 }
```

The $Body string is formatted like so:

```
<BLANK LINE>
Queue Cleared!
Server Name
Username
```

I wish to exact the Server name from the 4 line text string.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the format is consistent

```
if ($Body[2] -match '(?m:^Server (?<server>\w+))' ) {
    # do something with $matches.server
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a multi-line regex:

```
$body = @"

Queue Cleared!
Server Name
Username
"@

#$regex = '(?ms).+?$(.+)?$.+?$.+' #Capture second line.
$regex = '(?ms).+?$.+?$(.+)?$.+' #Capture third line.
$body -replace $regex,'$1'

Server Name
```

Each .+?$ represents one line of the body. The third line is captured and used for the -replace operation.

The title doesn't quite match the descripion in the post (second line vs third line) so I've included both.

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string using the `-split` operator:

```
$foo -split "`n"
```

You'll get an array back. You can then get an element from that array using indexing:

```
($foo -split "`r?`n")[2]
```

Comment: Brilliant! Tank you for the quick response! :)

Answer (score 0):

This will send only the 3rd item of the array (server name) to the Body.  The count starts at zero, so that's why [2] = 3rd.

```
 $Body[2] = $email.Body
```

Body result

```
Server Name
```